# Rules or laws for giving notice upon resigning?

Tags: notice-period

What are the rules or laws around giving notice upon accepting new job elsewhere??

I know most HR manuals say 2 weeks, but what are the legal requirements, if any??

I know the fire at will, quit at will idea.

I haven't received the formal offer or start date yet so I haven't done anything other than asking here.

Comment: The legal requirements are not universal.  Have you asked the company what their minimum notification period is?  You can get around the awkward question, of asking what the notice period is, before actually getting hire by requesting a copy of the HR manual. You should wait till you receive a firm offer.

Comment: There are no globally valid laws around this, asking about legal requirements needs *at least* a country, maybe even a state or smaller unit if that countries laws are fragmented like that.

Answer (score 2):

Generally whatever is in the contract you signed is the legal requirement, any legislated or regulated requirements would be built into it.

Some places there is no requirement. Others I have seen up to 3 months notice. There are ways around it if necessary but that would be a different question.

Comment: Many places have legal minimums that override anything in a contract if the contract violates those minimums. Some ocntracts don't mention it at all, which means the legal minimums apply.

Answer (score 1):

> I know most HR manuals say 2 weeks, but what are the legal
> requirements, if any??

In the United States, there are no federal or state laws that require employees to give any notice at all before quitting their jobs.

Comment: But there may be severance benefits that you lose if you quit without working the notice period. As others have said, know your contract.